# Find HTML button in JS based on innerhtml and click on it

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML code

```
 <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">I'm a button! Yayyy!</button> 
 </div>
```

I need to access that button in JS and click on it. And I cannot add an id to it, because it's on a webpage. (I'm using tampermonkey/greasemonkey btw)

Comment: Do you use JQuery as well? If yes, then you could write `$(".btn.btn-success" ).click(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do using jQuery.

```
$('.btn.btn-success:contains("I\'m a button! Yayyy!")')
```

^ would be your button.

If there's no other buttons with this text, the solution can be narrowed down to:

```
$('button:contains("I\'m a button! Yayyy!")')
```

If there can be another buttons, *containing* this text, and you want to address the button, which exactly matches it, the solution would be

```
$(".btn.btn-success").each(function(){
    if($(this).html()=="I'm a button! Yayyy!"){
        //$(this) there is the button you want
    }
})
```

Comment: Note that buttons with the text "I'm a button! Yayyy! Just kidding, I'm not." would be matched as well by this selector.

Comment: The second solution worked for me, the first one, no.

Comment: @Game made an edit: check the renewed first and second solutions. Every solution should work now. The previous second solution *was actually invalid*, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could select all the `button` elements on the page and then use the [`.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter them based on their [`.textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jcL6t0n4/)

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var filteredButtons = Array.prototype.filter.call(buttons, function (el) {
    return el.textContent.trim() === 'Find based on this text.';
});

// Click the first button
filteredButtons[0].click();
```

Of course in your case, you can select all the `.btn-success` elements that are descendants of elements with class `.form-actions`:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.form-actions .btn-success[type="submit"]');
var filteredButtons = Array.prototype.filter.call(buttons, function (el) {
    return el.textContent.trim() === 'Find based on this text.';
});

// Click the first button
filteredButtons[0].click();
```

Comment: If you only need the first button, you could use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and in the callback when a match is found, assign the match to a variable and return true to stop iterating.